# Want custom field should be mailed to client in gravity form plugin

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form plugin in worpress and i want some of the field should not be sent to client that field should only be displayed in admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the notification email from **Forms->Settings->Notifications**. If you haven't created a custom notification there should default notification at least.

At the bottom of the notification editor you can see "Message" field which is a wysiwyg-editor. By default it has **{all_fields}** variable in it which prints every field from your form. You can choose individual fields from a little button on the right side of the editor which looks like a grey square with a dark triangle on it. Delete {all_fields} from the editor and choose the ones you like from a dropdown list which opens when you click the button.

Comment: Thank you very much you help me a lot